# file extension - default

Tags: windows-xp

Anytime I download a video file, the extension is 'VLC Player', which does not seem to be able to burn onto a dvd-r disc for playback on my tv, via my dvd player. This exyension seems to be default...how may I change this so d/l'ed files show 'MPEG' or 'AVI', or whatever they are originally?

Answer (score 0):

The files are associated with VLC - their extensions should still indicate the file type. However, Windows hides these by default as soon as an association is known.

You can show these by going to the Tools menu in any Windows Explorer window, selecting Folder Options, clicking on the "View" tab, then unchecking the "Hide extensions for known file types" option.

If, on the other hand, you want to change the file association (the program the files open in by default), go to the "File Types" tab and click the "Change" button for the type you want to change.

Edit: Alternately, you can right-click on the file and go to "Open with..." and click "Choose Program", then select your program from the list.